# Make on Windows seems to fail creating or running temporary shells

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, make

I'm trying to build a project, [bootloader for AVR devices provided by LUFA](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/tree/master/Bootloaders/DFU), that uses GNU Make (`make`), but I am on Windows. While Windows, in and of itself, isn't necessarily the problem, it's clearly throwing a wrench in things.

I've installed `make` and other ancillary programs (grep, mingw, ...) via Chocolatey. I've also installed Cygwin/MinGW on their at times but believe I'm not using those binaries... but maybe they're not helping...

I'm running `make` and get an error before even the first make target is executed:

```
#...

test:
  echo test

#...
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\camer\git\Project\bootloader>make
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
echo test
test
```

`make -d` seems to show what is causing the `The system cannot find the path specified.` errors:

```
PS C:\Users\camer\git\Project\bootloader> make -d
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'Makefile'...
CreateProcess(C:\WINDOWS\system32\hostname.exe,hostname,...)
Main thread handle = 00000110
Reading makefile 'local.HOSTNAME.mk' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/LUFA/lufa-sources.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/LUFA/lufa-gcc.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/core.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/cppcheck.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/core.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/doxygen.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/core.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/dfu.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/core.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/gcc.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile 'LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/core.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Temp\make14552-1.bat
Batch file contents:
        @echo off
        mkdir -p obj 2> /dev/null
CreateProcess(C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Temp\make14552-1.bat,C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Temp\make14552-1.bat,...)
The system cannot find the path specified.
Cleaning up temporary batch file C:\Users\camer\AppData\Local\Temp\make14552-1.bat
...
```

So, it looks like `make` is trying some workaround on Windows that creates a temporary batch (`.bat`) file and executes that to get some output. Or maybe that's standard practice and it creates a `.sh` script on Linux... In any case, that seems to be what's failing for some reason.

Looking into LUFA's included Makefiles (`LUFA/LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/*.mk`), I can see the instructions that are trying to be run:

```
#...
# Create the output object file directory if it does not exist and add it to the virtual path list
$(shell mkdir -p $(OBJDIR) 2> /dev/null)
#...
```

So, something about Make's builtin `shell` is failing on Windows 10.

Curiously, these errors *do not* make the build fail. You can see in my example that `echo test` is still run.

It turns out, this is causing a litany of other issues with LUFA's Makefiles. The `shell` builtin is used to fill many make vars and many build steps expect those variables to be non-empty. Since the `shell` call fails without taking down the whole execution, everything breaks.

I'm not quite sure where next to look to solve my issue. Is it that I'm using a bad version of `make`? I've tried a few `make.exe` binaries from different places and they all have this error (if memory serves). I'm pretty sure I've had these make files working on a previous Windows installation but that computer is now offline so I cannot compare.

Thanks for the look! Cheers!

Comment: My opinion? (I know you didn't ask for).. use WSL to do this work rather than trying to cross-compile using Cygwin.  Also, "Cygwin/MinGW" are two completely separate UNIX emulation layers and suck differently depending on what you are trying do do.  It's odd to put them in a single statement as if they are a unit.  IMHO, MinGW is the superior of the two but that is a matter of opinion.  I myself use WSL(1) to do the kinds of compiles you are trying to do here.  Best part is that I can follow the Linux instructions without modifications.

Comment: I'm about to resort to WSL but that has its own set of complications. I could also just use one of my many linux machines. However, I'd rather get it to work without resorting to other technologies since I know I've gotten it to work without WSL/Linux. Frankly, I'm also interested in understanding what exactly *is* going on, and that's really my priority, and why I'm posting here. As for Cygwin/MinGW, afaiu, they both fill similar gaps in the Windows system if you just need some basic binaries. I have tried both independently (not trying to use both at once afaik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem was not creating new shells. The shells were being created as expected. The problem was the output redirect the `/dev/null`, which doesn't make sense on Windows.

The intermediate solution here is to not reference `/dev/null` in the makefile but instead redirect output to `nul`, the special `/dev/null` equivalent on Windows.